# Groups using SignalR & Redis

Tags: redis, signalr

Does SignalR.Redis support Groups? I am trying to implement SignalR using Redis, and messages are delivered properly when sent to All clients, but are not delivered when sent to a Group.

I am adding clients to group like so:

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "group1");
}
```

And sending to the group like so:

```
internal static void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessorHub>().Clients.Group("group1").showMessage(message);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SignalR scale-out providers are not currently ready for use.  Wait for the next release (beta of the scaleout providers) to use them.

On the implementation of the Redis scaleout provider & groups for the next release: Yes it will support groups.